# after Hadoop installation why cmd shows c:\program not recognized in an internal and external command when I want to see Hadoop version

Tags: windows, hadoop, cmd

When I run commands in cmd then an error shows that is `'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop prefers you don't have spaces in its installation paths.

That being said, Hadoop is not a "Windows program"; it doesn't need to be in `Program Files` folder.

Regarding the error, you additionally need to edit your OS `PATH` environment variable to include `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin`, as well as define `HADOOP_HOME`.

In addition, Hadoop does not support Java versions over 11. With 11 only being supported in version 3.3.4.